# Android: How do i set the source of imageview to a bitmap in a bitmap array

Tags: android, image

I am new to android and I am trying to do 1 small project in it..
I am trying to get a picture from the drawable folder and cutting it into 9 pieces and storing those pieces in a bitmap array..I was able to do that..

Now, how do i retrieve those pieces from the bitmap array and display it on the imageview?

I have used a gridview in the UI to show the images.... but am not able to assign the bitmap array to the imageResource...

ok, here is what i am trying to do..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    Activity activity=(Activity)mContext;
    Resources res=activity.getResources();
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Bitmap img=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.kite);
    createBitmapPieces(img);
    imageView.setImageResource(bmp[2]);//I dont know how to set the image from the array
}

public Bitmap[] createBitmapPieces(Bitmap source){

    int k=0;
    int width=source.getWidth();
    int height=source.getHeight();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        bmp[k]=Bitmap.createBitmap(source,(width*j)/3,(i*height)/3,width/3,height/3);
        k++;
    }

    }
    return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign only one Bitmap to an `ImageView`. If you want to use an array, you have to extend the `ImageView` class, and handle the array yourself in your custom `View`.

Two things you have to do:

**1.)** You have to create a public method for setting the `Bitmap` array to a new private field.

**2.)** You have to overwrite the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method and draw the `Bitmaps` in the array instead of drawing a single `Drawable`.

**EDIT:** I might have misunderstood your question, if you try to add the `Bitmaps` to the `GridView`, instead of a single `ImageView`, then you can do it with a custom adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap[] mPics;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Bitmap[] pics) {
        mContext = c;
        mPics = pics
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mPics.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mPics[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getItem(position)));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity`:

```
GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageview_id);
grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, YOUR_BITMAP_ARRAY));
```